# Calculation For Time Attendance System

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i had plot data from Entry Pass Scan in / out system into Database and write calculation in SQL script to generate Report in Aspx web page.

i had different type of shift pattern following by

```
EP_SHIFT_NAME   EP_SHIFT_DESC   EP_SHIFT_TIMEFR    EP_SHIFT_TIMETO
 R1             Off Day         09:00              23:59
 W1             W1              08:00              17:00
 R2             Rest Day        09:00              23:59
 D1             Day Shift       07:00              16:00
 NS             Normal Shift    08:00              17:30
 E1             Day Shift       08:00              17:00
 E2             Night Shift     20:00              05:00
 N1             Night Shift     19:00               04:00
```

Currently i had facing a problem  which is

1. Total actual  working minute(as Work MIn) is 720min per day[12 hours per day] (if more than 720 minutes working hours is consider under category Extra OT hour).
2. Cut off the scan in and out time from 0700 ~ 1900 (DAY) and  1900 ~ 0700(NIGHT) calculation.

However, if the person late in or early out the calculation of the time is base from the last and the first scan.

Anyone  can help me or amend the calculation in SQL Script ?

For the Work Hour calculation, i have a idea which is catch the (last scan time - EP_SHIFT_TIMEFROM) for every shift type

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),STUFF(STUFF(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':'),112) AS SCANDATE
           ,FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_COMPANY
           ,FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID
           ,FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            ,FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT
            ,right(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,6) AS FIRSTSCAN
           ,right(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,6) AS LASTSCAN
            ,SCANTIMECAL.INFAB AS INFAB_MIN
            ,SCANTIMECAL.OUTFAB AS OUTFAB_MIN
           ,DATEDIFF(MI,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
           ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) AS WORK_MIN
           ,DATEDIFF(HOUR,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
           ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) AS WORK_HOUR

            ,CASE WHEN FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R1' AND FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R2' 
              THEN ROUND(CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(STUFF(STUFF((CASE WHEN SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'N1' 
              THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE ,8)),112) + ' ' + 
              REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
               ELSE LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE ,8) + ' ' + 
               REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END),12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
                ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) / 60.0) AS FLOAT),2) 
                ELSE ROUND(CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
                ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) / 60.0) AS FLOAT),2) END AS OTWORK_HOUR

            ,CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'D1') 
            AND ROUND(CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(STUFF(STUFF((CASE WHEN SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'N1' 
             THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE ,8)),112) + ' ' + 
             REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
               ELSE LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE ,8) + ' ' + 
               REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END),12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
                ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) / 60.0) AS FLOAT),2) >= 3 THEN 3 - 0.25 END OTHOUR_FIX


            ,CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'D1') AND ROUND(CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(STUFF(STUFF((CASE WHEN SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'N1' 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE ,8)),112) + ' ' + 
              REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
               ELSE LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE ,8) + ' ' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END),12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
               ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) / 60.0) AS FLOAT),2) >= 3 
                THEN ROUND(CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(STUFF(STUFF((CASE WHEN SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'N1' 
                THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE ,8)),112) + ' ' + 
               REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
                ELSE LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE ,8) + ' ' + 
                REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END),12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME),
                 CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) / 60.0) AS FLOAT) - 3,2) ELSE 
                 CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R2') THEN ROUND(CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
                 ,Cast(STUFF(Stuff(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) / 60.0) AS FLOAT),2)END END OTHOUR_EXTRA



            ,CASE WHEN FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R1' AND FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R2' THEN FIRSTSCAN.LATEIN END LATEIN
            ,CASE WHEN FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R1' AND FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R2' THEN CASE WHEN SCANTIMECAL.OUTFAB >= SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_OGRACE THEN 1 END END AS BREAK_ABNORMAL
           ,CASE WHEN FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R1' AND FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R2' THEN CASE WHEN RIGHT(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,6) < REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO,108),108),':','') THEN 1 END END AS EARLYOUT_NORMAL
           ,(CASE WHEN FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT<> 'NS' AND FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R1' AND FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT <> 'R2' 
           THEN (CASE WHEN RIGHT(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,6) < REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+3,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO,108)),108),':','') THEN 1 END) END)AS EARLYOUT_SHIFT

            FROM
            (
            SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID,CASE WHEN RIGHT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,6) < '130000' AND  SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'N1' 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8),112)),112) 
            ELSE LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) 
            END ORDER BY SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID) AS RowNum
            ,SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE
            ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,6) < '130000' AND  SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'N1' 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8),112)),112) 
            ELSE LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) END AS EMP_WORKDATE
            ,EMPINFO.EP_EMP_COMPANY
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            ,SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT
            ,SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_ID
            ,SCANHIST.EP_TRANS_LOC
            ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,6) > REPLACE(SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMEFR,':','') THEN 1 END AS LATEIN
            FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SCAN_HIST] SCANHIST

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_EMP_INFO] EMPINFO
            ON EMPINFO.EP_EMP_ID = SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID


            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
            ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
            ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

            WHERE 1=1
            AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE >= '20130524' + ' ' + 
            CASE WHEN (SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT <> 'R1' AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT <> 'R2')
             THEN REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,-4,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMEFR + ':00'),108),':','') 
             ELSE REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,-0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMEFR + ':00'),108),':','') END
            AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE < CASE WHEN (SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'N1')  
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,'20130526'),112) + ' ' + 
            REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
            ELSE CASE WHEN (SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT = 'R2') 
            THEN '20130526' + ' ' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
            ELSE '20130526' + ' ' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END END
             AND SCANHIST.EP_TRANS_LOC = 'IN'
             AND EMPINFO.EP_EMP_LEVEL > '10'
            --AND EMPINFO.EP_EMP_LEVEL <> ''
           --AND SCANHIST.EP_EMP_DEPT = ''
           --AND SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SECTION = ''
           --AND SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT = ''
           --AND SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID = ''
           AND SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT ='A'
            )FIRSTSCAN



            OUTER APPLY
            (
            SELECT TOP 1
            SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE
            ,EMPINFO.EP_EMP_COMPANY
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            ,SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT
            ,SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_ID
            ,SCANHIST.EP_TRANS_LOC
            FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SCAN_HIST] SCANHIST

             JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_EMP_INFO] EMPINFO
            ON EMPINFO.EP_EMP_ID = SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID


          JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
         ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

           JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
            ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

        WHERE 1=1

           AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE > FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
           AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE < CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1') 
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)),112) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
           else CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R2') 
           THEN 
           left(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') ELSE 
           left(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END END
           AND SCANHIST.EP_TRANS_LOC = 'OUT'
           AND EMPINFO.EP_EMP_LEVEL > '10'
           AND EMPINFO.EP_EMP_LEVEL <> ''
           AND SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID = FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID

         ORDER BY SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE  )LASTSCAN  




         OUTER APPLY
          (
            SELECT 
             GROUP_SCANTIMECAL.EP_EMP_ID
        ,SUM(CAST(GROUP_SCANTIMECAL.INFAB_MIN AS FLOAT)) AS INFAB
            ,SUM(CAST(GROUP_SCANTIMECAL.OUTFAB_MIN AS FLOAT)) AS OUTFAB
            FROM
            (
          SELECT SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT
           ,SCANHIST.EP_TRANS_LOC
            ,DATEDIFF(MI,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME),
            CAST(STUFF(STUFF(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) AS INFAB_MIN
            ,DATEDIFF(MI,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME),
            CAST(STUFF(STUFF(PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) AS OUTFAB_MIN
            FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SCAN_HIST] SCANHIST

            OUTER APPLY
            (
            SELECT TOP 1
             NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_ID
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_TRANS_DESC
            ,NEXTSCAN.EP_TRANS_LOC
            FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SCAN_HIST] NEXTSCAN

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_EMP_INFO] EMPINFO
            ON EMPINFO.EP_EMP_ID = NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID


            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
            ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = NEXTSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

           JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
           ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

           WHERE 1=1
          AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_ID = NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_ID
           AND NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE > SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE
          AND NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE < CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1')
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)),112) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
           ELSE CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R2') 
           THEN 
           LEFT(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
           ELSE 
           LEFT(NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END END
          AND NEXTSCAN.EP_TRANS_LOC = 'OUT'
          ORDER BY NEXTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
            )NEXTSCAN

            OUTER APPLY
          (
            SELECT TOP 1
           PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_ID
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_NAME
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_DEPT
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_SECTION
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_ID
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_TRANS_DESC
            ,PREVSCAN.EP_TRANS_LOC
            FROM [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SCAN_HIST] PREVSCAN

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_EMP_INFO] EMPINFO
             ON EMPINFO.EP_EMP_ID = PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_ID

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
            ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = PREVSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
            ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

           WHERE 1=1
           AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_ID = PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_ID
            AND PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE > SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE
           AND PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE < CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1') 
           THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)),112) + ' ' + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
           ELSE CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R2') 
            THEN 
            LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
            REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') 
            ELSE 
            LEFT(SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
            REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END END
           AND PREVSCAN.EP_TRANS_LOC = 'IN'
            ORDER BY PREVSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
            )PREVSCAN

             JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_EMP_INFO] EMPINFO
             ON EMPINFO.EP_EMP_ID = SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID


            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
            ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SCANHIST.EP_EMP_SHIFT
           AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

            JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
           ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

         WHERE 1=1
            AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE >= FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE
           AND SCANHIST.EP_SCAN_DATE < CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'N1') 
             THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,+1,LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)),112) + ' ' +
               REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') ELSE
             CASE WHEN (FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R1' OR FIRSTSCAN.EP_SHIFT = 'R2')
              THEN 
              LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' + 
             REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+0,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','')
              ELSE 
              LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8) + ' ' +
                REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR,+6,SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_TIMETO + ':00'),108),':','') END END
            AND SCANHIST.EP_EMP_ID = FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID
            AND SCANHIST.EP_TRANS_LOC = 'IN'
            )GROUP_SCANTIMECAL

           GROUP BY GROUP_SCANTIMECAL.EP_EMP_ID


              )SCANTIMECAL

         JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_CALENDAR] SHIFTCAL
           ON SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_NAME = FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_SHIFT
            AND SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT_DATE = LEFT(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,8)

      JOIN [AcmkIMS].[dbo].[EP_SHIFT_DESC] SHIFTDESC
            ON SHIFTDESC.EP_SHIFT_NAME = SHIFTCAL.EP_SHIFT

             WHERE 1=1
           AND FIRSTSCAN.RowNum = 1
           AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),STUFF(STUFF(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':'),112) BETWEEN '20130524' AND '20130526'

           ORDER BY 
           FIRSTSCAN.EP_EMP_ID
```

Comment: can you please add the other tables structures and the desired structure of the final response, otherwise, this is quite a big query to try to response briefly.

Comment: I am scared of **`Big Queries` :)**

Comment: ,DATEDIFF(MI,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
           ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) AS WORK_MIN
           ,DATEDIFF(HOUR,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(FIRSTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)
           ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(LASTSCAN.EP_SCAN_DATE,12,0,':'),15,0,':') AS DATETIME)) AS WORK_HOUR

Comment: HI, it hard to strip it down due to use outer apply.